# Combining Two Models in Rails for a Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, forms, model

I'm very new with rails and I've been building a CMS application
backend.

All is going well, but I would like to know if this is possible?

Basically I have two models:

```
@page { id, name, number }

@extended_page { id, page_id, description, image }
```

The idea is that there are bunch of pages but NOT ALL pages have
extended_content. In the event that there is a page with extended
content then I want to be able to have a form that allows for editing
both of them.

In the controller:

```
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
@extended= Extended.find(:first, :conditions => ["page_id =
?",@page.id])
@combined = ... #merge the two somehow
```

So in the view:

```
<%- form_for @combined do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

...

<%= f.label :description %>
<%= f.text_field :description %>

<%- end >
```

This way in the controller, there only has to be one model that will be
updated (which will update to both).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off I don't think you need second model for this. You could simply define method `extended?` for `Page` model which returns `true` if all (or any) of the attributes of extended page model are present.

Also you may want to look into `fields_for` form helper method. Something like this should go into your view:

```
<%- form_for @combined do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%- f.fields_for(:extended_page) do |ef| %>

  <%= ef.label :image %>
  <%= ef.file :image %>
  <!-- other extended page form fields -->

<%- end %>

<!-- Other page form fields -->
<%- end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.  'Nested forms' and 'fields_for' is your answer.

```
<% form_for @combined do |form| %>
  <% form.fields_for :page do |nested_form| %>
    <%= nested_form.label :name %>
    <%= nested_form.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
  <% form.fields_for :extended_page do |nested_form| %>
    <%= nested_form.label :desciption %>
    <%= nested_form.text_field :description %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

The post params will look like

```
{ "combined" => 
     "page" => {"name" => "the name"},
     "extended_page" => {"description" => "the description"}
}
```

so you should be able to create a page and extended page by something like

```
page = Page.new(params[:combined][:page])
extended_page = ExtendedPage.new(params[:combined][:extended_page])
```